# SQL Query to extract numbers from string using patindex

Tags: sql-server

The below mentioned query runs fine, and extracts numbers from a string:

```
DECLARE @string varchar(100)

SET @string = N'"Total Comp A Commitments" means the aggregate of the Comp A Commitments, being £2,500,000 at the date of this Agreement.'

-- loop till there are characters left in a string
print LEN(@string)

WHILE PATINDEX('%[^0-9]%',@string) <> 0
BEGIN
    -- replace characters with empty space
    print 'iN lOOP'
    SET @string = STUFF(@string,PATINDEX('%[^0-9]%',@string),1,'')
END
SELECT @string
```

But I'm not able to make it work when the string has multiple numeric values like this:

> String = N'   "Total Comp A Commitments" means the aggregate of the Comp
>   A Commitments, being £2,500,000 at the date of this Agreement. "Total
>   Comp B Commitments" means the aggregate of the Comp B Commitments,
>   being £2,500,000 at the date of this Agreement. "Total Comp C
>   Commitments" means the aggregate of the Comp C Commitments, being
>   £2,500,000 at the date of this Agreement.'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If open to a Table Valued Function, consider the following.

Tired of extracting strings (left,right,charindex,patindex,etc.), I modified a parse function to accept two non-like delimiters.  In this case `'£'` and `' '`

Also being a TVF, it is easy to incorporate into a CROSS APPLY if your data is in a table.

**Example**

```
Declare @S varchar(max) = 'Total Comp A Commitments" means the aggregate of the Comp A Commitments, being £2,500,000 at the date of this Agreement. "Total Comp B Commitments" means the aggregate of the Comp B Commitments, being £2,500,000 at the date of this Agreement. "Total Comp C Commitments" means the aggregate of the Comp C Commitments, being £2,500,000 at the date of this Agreement.'

Select *
      ,AsMoney = try_convert(money,RetVal) 
 From  [dbo].[tvf-Str-Extract](@S,'£',' ')
 Where try_convert(money,RetVal) is not null
```

**Returns**

```
RetSeq  RetPos  RetVal      AsMoney
2       81      2,500,000   2500000.00
3       203     2,500,000   2500000.00
4       325     2,500,000   2500000.00
```

**The TVF if Interested**

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[tvf-Str-Extract] (@String varchar(max),@Delimiter1 varchar(100),@Delimiter2 varchar(100))
Returns Table 
As
Return (  

with   cte1(N)   As (Select 1 From (Values(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1)) N(N)),
       cte2(N)   As (Select Top (IsNull(DataLength(@String),0)) Row_Number() over (Order By (Select NULL)) From (Select N=1 From cte1 N1,cte1 N2,cte1 N3,cte1 N4,cte1 N5,cte1 N6) A ),
       cte3(N)   As (Select 1 Union All Select t.N+DataLength(@Delimiter1) From cte2 t Where Substring(@String,t.N,DataLength(@Delimiter1)) = @Delimiter1),
       cte4(N,L) As (Select S.N,IsNull(NullIf(CharIndex(@Delimiter1,@String,s.N),0)-S.N,8000) From cte3 S)

Select RetSeq = Row_Number() over (Order By N)
      ,RetPos = N
      ,RetVal = left(RetVal,charindex(@Delimiter2,RetVal)-1) 
 From  (
        Select *,RetVal = Substring(@String, N, L) 
         From  cte4
       ) A
 Where charindex(@Delimiter2,RetVal)>1

)
/*
Max Length of String 1MM characters

Declare @String varchar(max) = 'Dear [[FirstName]] [[LastName]], ...'
Select * From [dbo].[tvf-Str-Extract] (@String,'[[',']]')
*/
```

> **EDIT - Requested Sum**

```
Select AsMoney = sum(try_convert(money,RetVal) )
 From  [dbo].[tvf-Str-Extract](@S,'£',' ')
```

**Returns**

```
7500000.00
```

Comment: I want it to return sum of "AsMoney" column, how can we do that pls

Comment: @user3657339 See EDIT - Requested Sum

Comment: give me this error - Msg 537, Level 16, State 3, Line 24
Invalid length parameter passed to the LEFT or SUBSTRING function.

Comment: Declare @S varchar(max) = 'Total Comp A Commitments" means the aggregate of the Comp A Commitments, being £2,500,000 at the date of this Agreement. "Total Comp B Commitments" means the aggregate of the Comp B Commitments, being £2,500,000 at the date of this Agreement. "Total Comp C Commitments" means the aggregate of the Comp C Commitments, being £2,500,000 at the date of this Agreement.'

Select AsMoney = sum(try_convert(money,RetVal) )
 From  [dbo].[tvf-Str-Extract](@S,'£',' ')
 Where try_convert(money,RetVal) is not null

Comment: @user3657339 Remove the WHERE.   Not necessary due to the try_convert()